# Need help in understanding the below python string extraction

Tags: python

I read the below code about string extraction in python

```
text[text.find("insert"):(len(text),text.find("Configure"))[text.find("Configure")>1]]
```

and I am not able to understand this part

```
(len(text),text.find("Configure"))[text.find("Configure")>1]
```

How does this work? Can some one help me?

Comment: Just for the record, this is bad code. It would be much better to simplify it over two or three lines. And by the way, `text.find("Configure")>1` is an ugly way of saying `"Configure" in text`

Comment: Thanks for your reply this is not my code. I found it in the net and wanted to understand this. :)

Comment: As I said, this is bad code. You shouldn't be trying to understand every piece of code you find on the internet. It might just give you bad ideas of how to write your own. There is a very good reason why you didn't understand that code - it's very bad!

Comment: Sure thanks for warning! Just out of curiosity so how do you find a substring? The above code `text.find("Configure")>1` is telling to find the string "Configure". Do you suggest any better way for this?

Comment: As I said, to check if a substring is part of a string, you can just do `sub in string`. The use here of `> 1` is unclear to me. Usually one would do `s.find(substring) > -1`. The use of `> 1` means you want it specifically to be at lease in the second index which I don't see a reason why...

Answer (score 1):

There are several pieces of code involved in this one line:

I am considering variable `text` is of `str` type

1. `(len(text),text.find("Configure"))` This code will return a `tuple` of `int`, example: `(100, 10)`
2. `[text.find("Configure")>1]` This code will return a `list` of `bool` either `[True]` or `[False]`
3. Now combining both code blocks above, if index of `"Configure"` is greater than 1 then it will be `True` i.e. `1` so element in tuple at index `1` will be taken i.e. `10`, else condition will be `False` i.e. `0` so element at index `0` will be taken i.e. `100` (from the example tuple defined above)

```py
(len(text),text.find("Configure"))[text.find("Configure")>1]
```

4. The whole line boils down to:

```py
text[text.find("insert"):100]
```

or

```py
text[text.find("insert"):10]
```

and this is basic string slicing in Python

Comment: Point number 2 is wrong. This expression doesn't return a list. It's tuple slicing: `(...)[...]`

Comment: Thanks now I got it. I know about slicing but this way was quite new to me. So wanted to some help in understanding. :)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Its not tuple slicing, but simple indexing. For slicing you need `:` operator which tells the range, but there is only `(10, 100)[0]` single number `0`.

Comment: You are definitely right! In my head, indexing is a private case of slicing. Anyway, point being - this is not a list!

Answer (score 1):

It is [slicing operation.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html)
Please see the broken down parts of this slice.
Basically it is returning the slice of text from 'Insert' to 'Configure' provided 'Configure' comes after 'Insert'. If not then it returns entire string after 'Insert'. If 'Configure' comes before 'Insert' you get an empty string.

I do not understand the utility of writing this complex expression unless you can tell us about the code where you saw this. I advocate for not using this type of code.

```
text[
text.find("insert") #start index
:
(len(text),text.find("Configure"))  [text.find("Configure")>1]  # boolean behaving as subscript for entire string or till configure
]
```

Comment: Thanks got it now :)

Comment: Can you tell us about the src where you saw this? It is quite an ugly way to get the required string.  What do Insert and Configure represent?

Comment: Sorry I lost track of the site from where I picked this up. I kept this code aside to understand it. Thats all!

Answer (score 1):

`(len(text),text.find("Configure")` this part is creating a tuple of the length of the string and the index of the first instance of the word "Configure".

So if `text = '0000Configure000'` the tuple would become `(16, 4)`.

Now, the other part `[text.find("Configure")>1]` the condition is checking whether the index of the first instance of the word "Configure" is greater than 1.

Since in my example the index is 4 the condition becomes true and since it's inside a list
`[text.find("Configure")>1]` becomes `[True]`

Now,

```
(len(text),text.find("Configure"))[text.find("Configure")>1]
```

becomes :

```
(16, 4)[True]
```

And in python True is considered as 1 and False is considered as 0

so the code above can be written as

```
(16, 4)[1]
```

Which becomes the value `4`

Comment: *...and since it's inside a list...* - this is not a list... It's tuple slicing

Answer (score 1):

All of the answer with comments.

```
text1 = "sdgasdgasd insert blaBLAbla Configure"
text2 = "sdgasdgasd insert blaBLAbla Configur"

# For text1
# OUTPUT : (26, 17)
print((len(text1),text1.find("Configure")))

# OUTPUT : True also '1'
print(text1.find("Configure")>1)

# OUTPUT : 17 because '(26, 17)' is a list and '1' also second element is 17
print((len(text1),text1.find("Configure"))[text1.find("Configure")>1])

# from 'insert' until 'Configure' but
# if 'Configure' word in text1, 'Configure' not in print with string
# OUTPUT : 'insert blaBLAbla'
print(text1[text1.find("insert"):(len(text1),text1.find("Configure"))[text1.find("Configure")>1]])

# For text2
# OUTPUT : (36, -1)
print((len(text2),text2.find("Configure")))

# OUTPUT : False also '0'
print(text2.find("Configure")>1)

# OUTPUT : 36 because '(36, -1)' is a list and '0' also first element is 36
print((len(text2),text2.find("Configure"))[text2.find("Configure")>1])

# from 'insert' until 'Configure' but
# if 'Configur' word in text2, 'Configur' in print with string
# OUTPUT : 'insert blaBLAbla Configur'
print(text2[text2.find("insert"):(len(text2),text2.find("Configure"))[text2.find("Configure")>1]])
```